# How to get and set the wallpaper in objective c on Mac OSX?

Tags: objective-c, macos

I am looking for a way to get (and set) the wallpaper in objective c under Mac OS X.

Do you have code/pointer for this?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: "teh wallpaper" is called the desktop image on Mac OS X.

Comment: It's sad that Apple itself uses "wallpaper" on iPad/iPhone...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For OSX >= 10.6 use `NSWorkSpace`:

- [`-desktopImageURLForScreen:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000391-SW19)
- [`-setDesktopImageURL:forScreen:options:error:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000391-SW2)

For a `CFPreferences`-based solution see e.g. the [topdraw sources](http://code.google.com/p/topdraw/source/browse/trunk/Common/Installer.m?r=153):

```
CFStringRef appID = CFSTR("com.apple.desktop");
CFStringRef bkg   = CFSTR("Background");

// get:
NSDictionary *origBackgroundDict = (NSDictionary)CFPreferencesCopyAppValue(bkg, appID);

// ... 

// set and notify dock:
CFPreferencesSetAppValue(bkg, (CFPropertyListRef)backgroundDict, appID);
CFPreferencesAppSynchronize(appID);
[[NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
  postNotificationName:@"com.apple.desktop" object:@"BackgroundChanged"];
```

Comment: how to create live wallpaper